# About implement FloodFill algorithm in Object C

Tags: iphone, ios

I am very new with IOS and I am developing a funny painting app for iPhone & iPad which use Object - C.

The app will allow you to touch on a  the image then it will fill all the near and same color pixel with your touched pixel by your selected color (Paint bucket tool) .

I know Floodfill algorithm is what I need but I am really stuck on how to implement FloodFill algorithm to fill color on which area I want .

I also saw [that one](https://github.com/cenphoenix/ObjFloodFill/tree/master/src), but it just has 2 files and no any description, I tried to use it, but I wasnt sucessfull .

All I want is loading an image (like [that one](http://www.dragoart.com/tuts/pics/9/2685/11657/how-to-draw-a-cartoon-bull-step-6.jpg)) to ImageView , and it will fill color  when I touch on the ImageView.

Comment: Have A look here : https://github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Answer (score 0):

If you use UIBezierPath's for drawing you can use its -fill method to fill the shapes.

Comment: does UIBezierPath fully support my purpose that I can make a paint bucket tool ! hmmm... I just made a search and I see in the IOS doucment , it said "Paths can define simple shapes such as rectangles, ovals, and arcs..." . But I think it 's not about my question . Anyway thanks Diederik !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the byte data of the UIImage by access the CGImage of it.

From this you can find the colour of the pixel that was touched.

Then it's just a case of running a simple flood fill algorithm from the pixel that was touched.

Getting colour of pixel... [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Flood fill algorithm... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

I'd probably do this myself rather than look for a framework or anything.